# Are there restrictions on what types of Strings can be saved in SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android

I have a small, Serializable object I need to persist between sessions outside the context of an Activity. My first thought was to write it to a SharedPreferences file, but unfortunately that class doesn't have support for reading or writing a generic Serializable. But it does support String. So my next thought was: a Serializable is just an array of bytes, and a String is just an array of 2-byte chars... why not just chop my array up two bytes at a time, convert each pair of bytes into a char, and build a String out of those chars (and then do the reverse to read it back in)? I tried this and it works fine, *most of the time*. But once in a while, the object fails to serialize back in. After looking into it for a while, I realized that there was something fishy going on during the writes that precede the failed reads. Specifically, logcat shows the following exception being thrown (and caught) within the framework code during the write:

```
java.io.IOException: java.nio.charset.CoderResult[Malformed-input error with erroneous input length 1]
        at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.flush(FastXmlSerializer.java:225)
        at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.endDocument(FastXmlSerializer.java:183)
        at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeMapXml(XmlUtils.java:186)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.writeToFile(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:596)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$800(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:52)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$2.run(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:511)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.enqueueDiskWrite(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:532)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$100(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:52)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.commit(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:454)
```

This exception never propogates out to my code; as far it can tell, everything worked fine.

My best guess after reading the char documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) is that I sometimes by coincidence end up with a char whose numeric value puts it in the "high surrogate" range, that character is not followed by one in the "low surrogate" range, and as a result my String is just plain invalid (or at least able to confuse the SharedPreferences/XML code).

Naturally I could and probably will use regular file I/O or Base64 encoding instead, but I'd like to understand what's going wrong if possible.

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to do this. `SharedPreferences` simply get saved to an XML file. A `Serializable` object can however be written to an `ObjectOutputStream` and read back from an `ObjectInputStream`. Bearing in mind both of those can use the filesystem why would you use another filesystem mechanism (i.e., `SharedPreferences`) which isn't optimised for serialization?

Comment: @Squonk It's because it's just so darn convenient. I actually have several such objects I need to persist, and if I used regular file I/O I'd need to either have a separate file for each one or manually deal with the binary layout every time I did a read or write. I know the whole idea is terribly hacky and I'm not surprised it didn't quite work, but I'd still like to understand why.